# Change keyboard layout in Developer Console of a chromebook

Tags: linux, keyboard, chromium, chromebook, crouton-os

I have a Acer Chromebook that is running in Developer Mode. In ChromeOS and cosh I have a German keyboard. When I want to switch to Ubuntu (strg+alt+f2) I have to login to the Developer Console with the login account chronos. But here the keyboard layout/setting is EN-US. After typing in the commands crouton/ubuntu starts and the keyboard layout is German again.

How can I change/switch the keyboard layout in the Developer Console?
Is there a shell command for it?

[image: Picture of the Developer Console]

Answer (score 0):

The Developer Console, crosh, is a unix console, and unix commands generally apply. I'm not sure what the relevant command is offhand, but you can probably find it with some Google-fu.

Alternatively, the developer console is also accessible by pressing `Ctrl-Alt-T`, which opens crosh in a tab instead, then typing `shell`.

[image: crosh]

You can then change keyboard layouts using Chrome OS's graphical interface.

Check Chrome Options

[image: options]

Add a new language and select the corresponding keyboard layout

[image: select language]

The status bar now reflects the current keyboard layout

[image: status bar]

Clicking it will allow you to switch layouts
[image: keyboard]

[image: german]

Comment: it doesn't work anymore as solution now.